# Loop Plots in R using Rbokeh

Tags: r, loops, plot, bokeh, rbokeh

I am trying to loop a plots using rbokeh. but, I couldn't able to do it.

```
p1 <-figure(width=400, legend_location = NULL, xlab = "Time", ylab = "S1 Weight") %>%
ly_lines(`Dep Time (min)`,`S1 Weight`, data = Data,color= `Process Stage S1` ,hover = TRUE,width = 2) %>%
theme_axis("x", major_label_orientation = 90)

p2<-figure(width=400, legend_location = NULL, xlab = "Pass", ylab = "S1 Weight") %>%
ly_lines(Pass,`S1 Weight`, data = Data,color= `Process Stage S1` ,hover = TRUE,width = 2) %>%
theme_axis("x", major_label_orientation = 90)

grid_plot(list(p1, p2), same_axes = FALSE)
```

I was able to produce plots for 1 variable with the above code but, I am trying to plot all the variables with time and pass

Below is the head of the data I am referring too.

```
> head(as.data.frame(Data))
  Pass Elasped Time (min) Dep Time (min)  Process Stage S1  Process Stage S2 S1 Weight S2 Weight
1    0                0.0              0 FLAME POLISH MODE FLAME POLISH MODE     0.000     0.000
2    1                0.0              0 FLAME POLISH MODE FLAME POLISH MODE     0.000     0.000
3    1                0.1              0 FLAME POLISH MODE FLAME POLISH MODE     0.000     0.000
4    1                0.3              0 FLAME POLISH MODE FLAME POLISH MODE     0.000     0.000
5    1                0.5              0 FLAME POLISH MODE FLAME POLISH MODE     0.000     0.000
6    2                0.6              0 FLAME POLISH MODE FLAME POLISH MODE    -0.012     0.013
  Ramp Set V Vap Chamber C Vap Tank C Gecl4 Vessel Temp Gecl4 Hotbox Temp Gecl4 Hot Finger
1          0             0         69                80               115              143
2          0             0         69                80               115              143
3          0             0         70                80               115              125
4          0             0         71                80               116              117
5          0             0         71                80               115              121
6          0             0         72                80               115              124
 Vaporizer Load Vaporizer Pressure S1 Fume P S2 Fume P Hood P SMR Pressure S1 REB H2 S1 LEB H2
1           3.77               8.61         4         4      4       315.62      0.07         0
2           3.76               8.45         4         4      4       315.62      0.00         0
3           3.77               8.79         4         4      4       315.62      0.11         0
4           3.77               8.79         4         4      4       315.62      0.00         0
5           3.77               8.84         4         4      4       315.62      0.00         0
6           3.77               9.11         4         4      4       315.62      0.00         0
 S1 REB O2 S1 LEB O2 S1 INNER O2 S1 O2 S1 H2 S1 MAKE 02 S1 SICL4 1 S1 SICL4 2 S1 C2H2 S1 GECL4
1         0      0.00        2.94 19.74 40.40       2.86       0.45      -0.23    0.01     0.06
2         0      0.00        2.87 19.43 39.01       2.78       0.44      -0.20    0.00     0.01
3         0      0.04        2.95 19.77 40.25       2.90       0.47      -0.18    0.00     0.06
4         0      0.00        2.90 19.33 39.67       2.86       0.42      -0.24    0.00     0.03
5         0      0.02        2.94 19.74 40.62       2.90       0.44      -0.12    0.00     0.03
6         0      0.00        2.93 19.65 40.18       2.89       0.47      -0.18    0.00     0.03
```